# Erase all input data and input forms on a click of a button Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

Im trying to erase all my input boxes in a form on a click of a button. Im working on a "edit profile" functionality and when the user clicks the close button, all the input boxes will be erased and the input data will be erased and reverted back to it's previous values. This is what my html looks like ...

```
                <!-- Family and Freinds -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Fam">Family and Freinds</label>
                <div ng-repeat="info2 in infos.Family" id="Fam">
                    <div>{{info2}}&nbsp;<button type="button" class="close" ng-click="delete(info2, 2)">&times;</button></div>      
                </div>
                <input placeholder="Enter in a new family member or freind" type="text" ng-model='info2'>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add(info2, 3)">Add Freind/Family member</button>
            </div>
        </form> 
    </div>

    <!-- save and cancel -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <form role="form">
        <button id="save" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Save</button> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Close</button>
    </div>
```

I've tried using a type="reset" and other methods but nothing has worked so far. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than destroying the model object as explained by @Jason, one of the common way to do reset is to bind a copy of the original object to the form in the first place. Now cancelling becomes just throwing the entity always.

This requires that you structure your model as object and not direct properties on $scope. 
You then do something like

`$scope.infosEdit=angular.copy(infos);`

and bind your view to the property `infosEdit`.

Now cancel call becomes

`$scope.infosEdit=angular.copy(infos);`

which is as good as reverting the changes back to original.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this out

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an ng-click to your close button and reset/delete the scope data in your controller eg:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="resetForm()"> Close</button>
```

Then in your controller

```
$scope.resetForm = function() {
    delete $scope.infos;
}
```